Selected Previous Amount in DAX
I have a FactTable with FiscaLWeeks and its Rank. But at one point calculating Previous Week Amount fails.
   Previous Week = 

CALCULATE( 
            SUM(FactTable[Amount]),
            KEEPFILTERS('FactTable'[Week] = MAX('FactTable'[Week] )
    )) 
Current Week = 

CALCULATE( 
            SUM(FactTable[Amount]),
            KEEPFILTERS('FactTable'[Rank] = MIN('FactTable'[Rank] )
    )) 

the Problem
when I select 3 dates, it considers, Previous Week = FY24 WK49 (as the earliest week) rather than FY24 WK50 (which is the closest week to the selected Current Week)  where the Current Week = FY24 WK52 (which is the last selected week and it is correct)

the sample data
Rank Product    Amount  FiscalWeeks
1   R   10  FY24 WK52
1   A   5   FY24 WK52
2   R   35  FY24 WK51
2   A   5   FY24 WK51
3   R   20  FY24 WK50
3   A   10  FY24 WK50
4   R   25  FY24 WK49
4   A   25  FY24 WK49
5   R   15  FY24 WK48
5   A   5   FY24 WK48
6   R   30  FY24 WK47
6   A   20  FY24 WK47
7   R   15  FY24 WK46
7   A   25  FY24 WK46
8   R   10  FY24 WK45
8   A   40  FY24 WK45

Expected Answer
Current Week 15 
Previous Week 30 (the week closest to the current week)


Can you share some data ?

let me clarify your logic. If you select week, 49, 50 and 52. The current week is the last one which is week 52? then which week is the previous week?

the previous week would be 50. the one closest to the current week (52).

Is this the effect you are looking for?
The code below checks to see if one filter is being applied, if so, then returns blank. Otherwise it should return whatever the closest other selected slicer value happens to be.
The closest value is the top 1 result of rank after excluding the maximum week from consideration.
Previous Week = 
IF(NOT HASONEFILTER(Data[FiscalWeeks]),

CALCULATE( 
            SUMX(
                TOPN(1, Data, [Rank], ASC),
                Data[Amount]
            ),
            Data[Week] < max(Data[Week])
    ))

(Fact Table = Data, and I am assuming the [week] column was supposed to be the integer value of fiscal week)
